# How to Build and debug Open cv project in Eclipse?

Tags: opencv

I have configure all the libraries and path required for running open cv in c/c++ mode in eclipse, i have written the below code, but i  don't know how to build and debug, 
my code is

```
 #include "cv.h"
 #include "highgui.h"
//using namespace cv;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 cvNamedWindow( "Example1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
IplImage* img = cvLoadImage("prado.jpg",1);
cvShowImage("Example1", img );//*/
cvWaitKey(0);
return 0; 
}
```

Comment: This is old openCV1 interface (cvShowImage, IplImage, etc). See [this document](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/core/interoperability_with_OpenCV_1/interoperability_with_OpenCV_1.html?highlight=cvshowimage) ... but as you are starting out with a new installation you should stick to the current interface otherwise you will get still more confused.

Comment: 1 / Have you checked your install? How do you know it is working?  2/ your include paths look a little ... local... have you checked their locations? 3 / uncomment //using namespace cv  4 / rewrite using openCV2 as you had previously, and edit the question with your latest results. 5 / Is "prado.jpg" in the same location as this code? 6 / you can revert to int main() for now if you are using a hard-coded image name

Comment: yeah i have installed it,

Comment: i am using  the library #include<cv.h>  and it shows no error so, i think i have include lib and opencv file correctly,,, any further comments..plz

Comment: You have installed it, but have you TESTED it, how do you know it is working? see my last comment edit...

Comment: @HeWas    it gives some error in makefile, after using "int main()" and also using namespace cv4 and using namespace openCV2 gives an error...

Comment: You are trying too fast and not explaining what you are doing. Also you have not accepted my previous answer. Please do that first. Then tidy up this question (it should lead off the previous answer). Explain exactly what you are doing. Read the docs carefully. Are you following [this guide](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html)? If so say so, and show exactly where you get stuck. If not read it first.

Comment: @HeWas Sorry for inconvience, actually i have the above code, and i am using the tutorial http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/doc/tutorials/introduction/linux_eclipse/linux_eclipse.html   but when i go to Run-->Run Configuration, and i follow the exact step describe in that tutorial, and at last when i click the apply and ok button, then i got error in "makefile"

Comment: i am getting this error in makefile under Debug folder "@echo 'Invoking: Cross GCC Linker'"  " @echo 'Building target: $@'"